# How do I capture packets between a WiFi router and an internet modem?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, tcp, sniffing

In my home all devices were connected to my router.  I want to capture all traffic so I have done below connection:

```
Modem --- (Ethernet to USB Adapter) --> Laptop (Windows 10) --- (Ethernet CABLE) ---> Router
```

I have purchased USB-to-Ethernet adapter (for a 2nd Ethernet port on laptop), and used it to connect Modem - Laptop - router, that is, the laptop is now in a man-in-the-middle configuration.

Now In windows, I can see two Network connection Network1, Network2.
Then I have selected above two Network in Windows 10 and create Bridge.
Now from router I can access internet and also In Windows 10, wireshark software can also be able to show traffic

Now when I try to capture traffic, it does not shows me any HTTP request, It just shows me IP addresses.

Any one please help me how to capture http traffic in this connection? Am I doing something wrong?

Below is my network connection
https://www.imageupload.net/image/Kc5zd

Below is what I can able to capture in wireshark
https://www.imageupload.net/image/KcYX8

Comment: On which interface do you have Wireshark capturing packets?   *"it does not shows me any HTTP request"* -- From where are you creating these HTTP requests? The laptop performing the capture, or another PC in your LAN?    FYI your laptop is no longer in your LAN since it's on the WAN side of your router.

Comment: Hi Sorry for late, I am using bridge interface, LAPTOP is performing capture, No my LAPTOP is connected with LAN only. I have turned off my WIFI, I want to intercept all data between modem and router in bridge interface.

Answer (score 0):

You might be more interested in using a DNS service to capture traffic. While you have successfully setup a network bridge, Wireshark will only give you raw information, also **most of the data is encrypted using https.** This means you will not be able to see what data is being sent. You can use a DNS service to track DNS requests instead.

Some features include:

> It maps every IP address into a domain name. So when you log in to check your logs and statistics, you don’t need to figure what the numbers mean. You view a list that makes sense. You can even search for certain words or web sites. <sup>[[1]](https://awildduck.com/?p=6075)</sup>

> It permits you to block websites based on a very rich set of 100 criteria, including violence, adult content, hate speech, etc. <sup>[[1]](https://awildduck.com/?p=6075)</sup>

## Using OpenDNS to track DNS Requests

There is a write-up here: https://awildduck.com/?p=6075

It explains how to utilize OpenDNS to track what sites are being looked up. You set the dns on the router, so all devices connected to the router will be monitored.

> - Configure your router to use the two DNS servers at OpenDNS.com  (Replace default DNS server addresses with 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220)
> - Create a free account on their web site.
> - Then, **enable the logging feature.**

Comment: Sorry but I am interested in all https and http request and want to intercept data,

Comment: Can't I decrypt those data? will you please help me ?